# Outlook fully justifying text for HTML emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

We're having an issue where Outlook is trying render an HTML email with fully justifed text.  This is causing extra spaces to show up between words like you might see in InDesign or in Print.  Here is a sample of the top protion of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <!-- Disables auto linking telephone where its supported -->
 <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no"> <!-- Disables auto linking date where its supported -->
 <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no"> <!-- Disables auto linking address where its supported -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400&amp;family=Red+Hat+Display:wght@500;700;900&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title></title>
```

We are also using basic TR TD structure for the paragraph...EX

```
<tr>
     <td valign="top" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;"><p style="color: #2f3942; font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:300; margin: 0 0 0 0; text-align: left; line-height: 1.35em;">random text here</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

We tried forsing the spacing to be "normal" by adding nbsp; but obviously that's a hack and not ideal  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We also tried using older TDs from previouly validated emails and replacing the copy but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you supply more code? Such as a test file that may or may not closely align with your template, but shows the justification bug in play. This latest bug is down to the latest MS 365 update on Apr 11th, but there is yet to be a fix for it. The email development community are actively looking into a workaround but nothing yet. People are also seeing it randomly being applied, so if you can supply a test for us to see if we can replicate the bug, that'll help immensely.